# How to convert createdAt date field to string in Parse.com?

Tags: android, string, date, parse-platform

I want to fetch the createdAt field from a Parse.com database. How do I convert it to a string?

I was trying the code below.

```
Log.d("stats", "date = " + List.get(i).getDate("createdAt").toString());
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? you have given it correctly. If it is java.util.Date then your code will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List.get(i).getCreatedAt()
```

returns a Java Date object. You can convert that with Format, depending on your desired output, i.e.:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String s = formatter.format(List.get(i).getCreatedAt());
```

which will give you something like 2014-04-15 16:34:27

Comment: thanks, by the way how can i convert to a format like the output in iOS 2015-07-25 16:34:28 +0000, something like that

Comment: @A.Adam Check SimpleDateFormat docs for formatting details (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and use this page for testing until you achieve the desired format: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm